# What does x-apple-data-detectors do within a href?

Tags: html

When checking a site I am working on for broken links, I found this:

```
<a href="x-apple-data-detectors://6">.</a>
```

I tried googling, but all I can find about it seem to be about this form:

```
<a href="#" x-apple-data-detectors="false">
```

What is the intention when this appears in a href?

Comment: I would check any JS loaded on the site to see if there is a function doing things with specific hrefs.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the intention when this appears in a href?

No intention. It's just broken.

The `x-apple-data-detectors` URI scheme is used internally by some Apple applications on iOS and macOS to automatically insert clickable links for certain types of information (like phone numbers, dates, and locations). These links have no meaning outside this context; this one probably slipped in by mistake.

Comment: I see. So for example, maybe someone copied content from Apple Mail into a blog post they were writing. Similar to junk HTML you might get when you copy from Microsoft Word. Thanks!